# A/B Testing with Adobe Target in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, adobe-analytics

I'm working on iOS app that uses adobe target to do A/B testing. When user logs in it divides traffic into two buckets A and B respectively using adobe target, now my question is can we put conditions i.e if I have calendar in my app then bucket A can see weekly and bucket B can see monthly calendar?

I have tried searching online but couldn't find something valuable, I know I can divide in different proportions, I know I have two different flows for bucket A and B but can I put condition in that flow through coding?

Comment: The only time I have done something like this is with a hybrid app that I set a JS variable then triggered a different action based on that variable.  I don't have enough information about your app to give you any more guidance then this.

Comment: It gives me a hope that it can be done that way but I wanted more by SDK. This trick can be performed but I want to see if adobe give this by default. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It can be achieved through custom JS

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this will need to send wether or now the user has the calendar as a param in an mbox call.

Then you can setup a profile to look at that param and put the person into either a or b.  Then you can add targeting rules based on the value of that profile.

Profiles are setup inside of Target but are programmed via JavaScrip that runs server side on Adobe's servers.